# Python web crawler not finding keywords which are present

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape multiple websites (using python 2.7) to find out if specific keywords exits within them or not. My code:

```
import urllib2
import csv

fieldnames = ['Website', '@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

def csv_writerheader(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()

def csv_writer(dictdata, path):
    with open(path, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(dictdata)

csv_output_file = 'EXPORT_Results!.csv'
# LIST OF KEY WORDS (TITLE CASE TO MATCH FIELD NAMES)
keywords = ['@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

csv_writerheader(csv_output_file)

with open('top1m-edited.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        # INITIALIZE DICT
        data = {'Website': strdomain}

        if '.nl' in strdomain:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
                response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                html_content = response.read()

                # ITERATE THROUGH EACH KEY AND UPDATE DICT
                for searchstring in keywords:
                    if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'found'
                    else:
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'not found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'not found'

                # CALL METHOD PASSING DICT AND OUTPUT FILE
                csv_writer(data, csv_output_file)

            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                print (strdomain, 'HTTP ERROR')

            except urllib2.URLError:
                print (strdomain, 'URL ERROR')

            except urllib2.socket.error:
                print (strdomain, 'SOCKET ERROR')

            except urllib2.ssl.CertificateError:
                print (strdomain, 'SSL Certificate ERROR')

f.close()
```

However, my crawler seems not to be very accurate on this matter.

For example: I'm scraping a list of websites to find out whether they do or do not contain keywords like `@media` and `googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` in their source code. When the script is done running, I manually check the results for accuracy. After the manual check (searching the keywords on URL's source code with Inspect Element via Chrome) I discover that certain websites DO contain `@media` and/or `googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` in their source code whereas my crawler said that these  websites DO NOT contain these keywords.

Maybe this has to do with the fact that a website's code found by using Chrome's "Inspect Element" doesn't **exactly** match the code (of the same website) found by using Chrome's "View-source". For example, [this](https://www.rocmn.nl/) website contains `googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` in its "Inspect Element"-code but not in its "View-source"-code.

My question: can it be that my crawler is purely scraping the "View-source"-codes of the websites and not their "Inspect Element"-codes (where it should also be looking)?

If this is my problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will start working on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the source code of a web page and what you see by launching the Chrome Web Developer are *two different things*.

Why ? The source code is the raw HTML page as sent by the server. What you see in the Chrome Web Developer or Firebug (for example, by clicking on "Inspect Element") is the *Document Object Model (DOM)* of the page : the source code your browser has parsed and in which the JavaScript elements have been launched.

But Javascript can completely modify the page without touching the source code.

[Here is an example.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first) By clicking on "change content", you will see that the content of the Web page (in the right windows) has changed completely while the source code (in the left window) is still the same.

In your example, `googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js`, the `async` term is a clue that this page loads elements using AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) techniques.

So, you'll need a Python script that can handle JavaScript. There are several possibilities, for example using the Selenium or Dryscrape modules.

Here is a basic and slow example with Selenium, BeautifulSoup (to parse the HTML before searching) and regular expressions (because your are searching words in a text, not a particular HTML element)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import re

def get_keywords(source_url, keywords):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(source_url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for names in keywords:
        re.escape(names)
    search = "(" + "|".join(keywords) + ")"
    pattern = re.compile(search)
    print(pattern.findall(str(soup)))
    driver.quit()       

keywords = ['https://www.rocmn.nl/roc-midden-nederland', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

get_keywords('https://www.rocmn.nl/', keywords)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.rocmn.nl/roc-midden-nederland', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']
```

Comment: so i tried your code and only changed the `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` to `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')`. However, I keep getting this code: `File "C:/Users/Jacob/PycharmProjects/Testing/fooling around 3.py", line 8
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`. Moreover, I don't really see I can used your method to auto scrape URLs from a CSV

Comment: The indentation error was caused by the comment inside the function. Now it works. There are many way to use it for scraping a list of URL, but your question was not "could you write and entire program for me ?"